# paragraph tag not changing color

Tags: html, css

From the below code:  why paragraph tag not showing green? Iam just practising CSS, so I came across with this doubt..

```
p .marked2{
color:green;
}

.marked p
{
color:purple;
}


<p class="marked2">This is a green paragraph.</p> //HERE NOT SHOWING GREEN
<div class="marked">
<p>This is a purple paragraph.</p> //HERE GETTING PURPLE COLOR
</div>
```

please clear me this..

Comment: Should be `p.marked2`.  The way you have it now, it's looking for `.marked2` elements inside of any `p` container.

Comment: there is no space required for `p .marked2`. If you remove space it will work.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/uQ8yS/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `p.marked2`.  The way you have it now, it's looking for `.marked2` elements inside of any `p` container.

**Examples:**

`p.marked2` will target `<p class="marked2">...</p>` (*every* `p` element with `class="marked2"`)

`p .marked2` will target `<p><span class="marked2">...</span></p>` (*any* kind of element with `class="marked2"` as *any descendent* of `<p>`)

Comment: @Clarsen - welcome to SO.  If an answer solves your problem, the community appreciates if you mark it as "solved" (with the checkmark under the voting).  :)

Answer (score 0):

erase space

```
p.marked2 { 
    color:green; 
}
```

Comment: the css is poorly formed given the structure. edit: if this proliferates it will cause additional issues - edit 2: you are right that this "would solve the snippet" but it doesnt provide a "correct adjustment" - perhaps im an idealist.

Comment: @Brandt - If you're the downvoter, that's pretty low.  This answer was posted at the same time as yours, and it's more clear - your answer duplicates the incorrect code!

Comment: No obfustication - I did. However I suppose you are correct, "kids these days" don't want to understand rather they want an answer. To those ends I concede.

Comment: @seun / Steve - added caveats to the comments/ responses. In this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Clarsen it you should write like this :-

```
p.marked2 {
color:green;
}

.marked p {
color:purple;
}
```

And its working now as per your requirement....

Actually the you wrote `p .marked2` this means when `marked2` **class** will come with `P` tag not inside the `P` tag than the property will apply.

So you should write like this `p.marked2` than `marked2` **class** property will apply into your `P` tag as like the Demo.

[**DEMO**](http://tinkerbin.com/5hz157Yd)

Answer (score 0):

I just got it work. All you have to do is take the space out of

```
    p .marked2{
    color:green;
    }




    p.marked2{
    color:green;
    }
```

That's it boss... you are good to go now...

Comment: Sparky672 was the first to give the same solution :P.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem your having is with the space; Example: `p .marked2`.  All you need to do is delete the space like this; Example: `p.marked2`. It should work fine after that.

`p.marked2{
   color:green;
}`

`p.marked{
   color:purple;
}`

`<p class="marked2">This is a green paragraph.</p> //HERE NOT SHOWING GREEN
<div class="marked">
<p>This is a purple paragraph.</p> //HERE GETTING PURPLE COLOR
</div>`